# Use python function to get key by value in dictionary and return either key or "None'

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to return only the key value '20' but instead my function returns 'None'. I only want it to return None if value is not in my input dictionary.

```
def find_key(input_dict, value):
for key,val in input_dict.items():
    if val == value:
       return key
    else: 
        return "None"

find_key({100:'a', 20:'b', 3:'c', 400:'d'}, 'b')
```

Comment: The function returned after the first iteration of the for loop because one of the `if` clause is true.

Comment: Thanks Jerie, I changed the code. But why does it return "None" and not 20?

Comment: Your edited code has the same issue. Please refer to my answer below.

Comment: If it helps, think of `return` as `break` but more powerful because it not only breaks out of the loop but also "breaks" out of the function

Comment: Any reason you don't reverse your key/values in your dictionary?  Then it would just be `return input_dict.get(key,None)`.

Comment: If the first value doesn't match, the code returns None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revise your function to be

```py
def find_key(input_dict, value):
    for key, val in input_dict.items():
        if val == value: return key
    return "None"
```

which means the function only returns the string `"None"` if the loop has already ended. In your original version, the loop will exit after the first iteration because it hits a `return` keyword. Also, if you are returning special Python `None` instead of a string `"None"`, you don't even need to return anything explicitly because `None` is the default return value of a function without a `return` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

This returns the first matched key or None:

```
def find_key(input_dict, value):
    result = "None"
    for key,val in input_dict.items():
        if val == value:
            result = key
    return result
key = find_key({100:'a', 20:'b', 3:'c', 400:'d'}, 'b')
print(key) # 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't know if your dictionary has multiple values like the one you're looking for, you should consider returning a list of keys.

Also, returning `'None'` is probably a mistake, you should consider returning `None` (not a string with the word 'None', but the actual `None` value), which is more useful in Python.

As a result, I'd use:

```
def find_keys(d, value):
    result = [key for key, x in d.items() if x == value]
    return result if result else None
```

Or, since `[]` is pretty clear if you're returning a list, simply:

```
def find_keys(d, value):
    return [key for key, x in d.items() if x == value]
```

Apart from covering all cases, I like this solution the best because if you read the code out loud, it's pretty obvious what it does, as well as performing well.

Answer (score 0):

```
value_key_dict = {value: key for key, value in dic7.items()}
searched_key = value_key_dict[any_value]
```

Comment: Please, add a brief explanation of how/why it solves the problem.

Comment: With "value_key_dict" You can search by value and obtain the key. It is easy to understand.